# Error in starting LibreOffice, libuno_sal.so.3 missing

Tags: xubuntu, 17.10, libreoffice

When i try to open libreoffice i get this error:

> /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: error while loading shared
>   libraries : libuno_sal.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Before that i purged libreoffice because it didn't start up anymore. So this error may be caused by a incomplete new installation.
The used OS is Xubuntu 17.10.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04.1.